# How to implement this relationship in Eloquent?

Tags: eloquent

I have SQL this query:

```
    SELECT f.follower_id, u.fname, u.lname
    FROM followers f
    INNER JOIN users u ON f.follower_id = u.id
    WHERE f.user_id = $user_id
    AND u.status = 1
    ORDER BY fname, lname
    LIMIT 10
```

I have two models: User and Follower.

A user can have many followers, and each follower has its own user data. I want to be able to get all of a user's followers (who have a status of 1) by doing something like this:

```
$followers = User::get_followers();
```

Comment: See here how to correctly implement many to many relation with Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `User` model:

```php
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id')
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->orderBy('fname')
        ->orderBy('lname');
}
```

Then you can access them like this:

```php
$followers = $user->followers;
```

Comment: In my user model, I pasted your code. In my controller, I added this code: `$followers = $user->followers;`. I printed $followers and did not get the expected results.

Comment: Yes, $followers is empty.

Comment: Post the result of `dd($user->followers()->toSql());`.

Comment: I even tried trimming down the function to this: `return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');`

Comment: select * from `users` inner join `followers` on `users`.`id` = `followers`.`follower_id` where `followers`.`user_id` is null

Comment: The problem is `$user`. How did you create it?

Comment: $user = User::find($user->id); // coming from session

Comment: Can you add the `User` model to your question?

Comment: Actually I think your answer works. Thanks for your help.